# (warning)FAILED to scan JAR (error)FAILED to process JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

My web application running on tomcat and complied by maven is giving the warnings and errors below. I can see all the JARs in my local repository though can someone please help.

```
WARNING: Failed to scan JAR [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/webapps/F_Quote-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/spring-webflow-2.4.0.BUILD-20130620.194537-39.jar] from WEB-INF/lib
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
................


WARNING: Failed to scan JAR [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/webapps/F_Quote-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/spring-binding-2.4.0.BUILD-20130620.194537-39.jar] from WEB-INF/lib
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Sour
...........

WARNING: Failed to scan JAR [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/webapps/F_Quote-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/spring-js-resources-2.4.0.BUILD-20130620.194537-39.jar] from WEB-INF/lib
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Sour
.......

WARNING: Failed to scan JAR [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/webapps/F_Quote-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/spring-js-2.4.0.BUILD-20130620.194537-39.jar] from WEB-INF/lib
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Sour
........

SEVERE: Failed to process JAR found at URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/webapps/F_Quote-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/spring-js-resources-2.4.0.BUILD-20130620.194537-39.jar!/] for ServletContainerInitializers for context with name [/F_Quote-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Oct 24, 2013 2:26:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig configureStart
SEVERE: Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
Oct 24, 2013 2:26:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
WARNING: Failed to process JAR [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/webapps/F_Quote-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/spring-webflow-2.4.0.BUILD-20130620.194537-39.jar!/] for TLD files
```

This is my pom.xml file. In my local repository I can see all the JARS that are said to be missing. But in my eclipse when i expand the maven repository there's nothing inside the missing JAR.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">  
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.farchis</groupId>
  <artifactId>F_Quote</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Farchis Estimator</name>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id> 
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
    </repository>   
    <repository>
        <id>org.springsource.maven.snapshot</id>
        <name>SpringSource Maven Central-compatible Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>     
        <version>1.3</version>      
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>     
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- // -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>        
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>   
     -->
    <!-- // -->

    <!-- Tomcat 6 need this 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>20030825.184428</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
   <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

     JSR-330 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    --> 
  </dependencies>    
</project>
```

Comment: I had the same problem. Deleting the jar solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem also, but removing the jar file is not an option. The jar files unable to be processed are the tomcat jar files needed to run the server. However, after reading the comment in the OP, I tried moving the jar files from lib to a temp location, attempting to start tomcat and seeing the expected error message, and then copying the files back to lib. This worked. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the jar file was damaged because of interruption during download. You may delete the jar and download again then try.

I had this problem also, this solution is worked good for me.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when you use a dependency and this dependency has another  dependency. when this parent dependency has scope like compiler.
it say I wont use this dependency in runtime so when you say run project, maven say I cant find child dependency for runtime.
so I think you can control your dependencies and if you delete your dependency version which one giving error, and if you give the right scope I think your problem will solve.

More information for scope:
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

example I solved in my project.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate-jpamodelgen}</version>
 </dependency>
```

Error:

```
/Users/vahap/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar (No such file or directory)
```

after I deleted version: because hibernate-jpamodelgen using compiler scope. when I add compiler scope problem resolved for me

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```